# How to create installer for linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have created rpm for my software which works fine for fedora. But this fails whenever I want to install the same in linux mint. because linux mint supprts .deb file for installation. So I want to create installer package for my software which will be compatible in linux mint.

Comment: You might also get support from serverfault for this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the program [`alien`](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/alien/), which allows you to manipulate foreign packages on a linux distro.  Note that this is fine for installing simple packages, but you should [build the package from source](http://wiki.freegeek.org/index.php/Basic_Debian_Packaging) if you intend to distribute to a large audience.

Answer (score 0):

Another great tool at your disposal for this would be fpm. It allows to create several different package types from many different things, like rpm's.  It currently works with the following:

Sources:

- gem (even autodownloaded for you)
- python modules (autodownload for you)
- pear (also downloads for you)
- directories
- tar(.gz) archives
- rpm
- deb
- node packages (npm)

Targets:

- deb
- rpm
- solaris
- tar
- directories
- Mac OS X .pkg files (osxpkg)

You can find it here: https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm

Answer (score 0):

you can use alien if you want and that's the recommended way to do it actually, but you can install it with rpm too. just install rpm:`sudo apt-get install rpm` then run `sudo rpm -i package_name`